# A reason of "SSL_ERROR_RX_MALFORMED_HELLO_RETRY_REQUEST" error in FF when connecting wirh Firefox (TLS 1.3)

Tags: tls

I am trying to test my server program which implements TLS 1.3 connection - it should establish TLS 1.3 connection.
My server uses a self-signed certificate, created in `openssl`.
I am using Firefox v.112 as the client to connect and getting an error - `"SSL_ERROR_RX_MALFORMED_HELLO_RETRY_REQUEST"`.
How can I know the specific reason and details of this error ?

Comment: It sounds like the reason is that your HelloRetry request is malformed from the error message.  Also, implementing TLS is nontrivial and has a lot of security sensitive behaviour.  You probably should use a well-known implementation like OpenSSL instead.